# Access SFTP from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sftp

I have a need where i have to open a SFTP connection with a server, copy a file from there to local.

To that end, i have tried installing node-sftp module using

```
npm install node-sftp
```

It didnt work out of the box, i had to replace the sftp.js file that was installed by npm with that of github repository here : https://github.com/ajaxorg/node-sftp

(npm version was using TTY and github version was using PTY. i am not sure what they are)

After start the server and invoking the code, i see this in console.

```
launching: sftp -o Port=22 jash@xxx.63.xxx.49
listening...
```

console just hangs here. I am trying to print all files in the current directory after connection is opened.

This is the code

```
var http = require('http');
var Sftp = require('node-sftp');
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
var msgHandler = function(request, response) {
    var options = {
        host:"xxx.63.xxx.49",
        username:"jash",
        password:"mypassword",
        port:22
    };
    var conn = new Sftp(options,function(err){
       console.log(err);
    });
    conn.cd(".", function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        conn.ls(".", function(err, res) {
            console.log(res[0].path);
        });
    });
    console.log("listening...");
}

http.createServer(msgHandler).listen(port);
```

The credentials are fine, i used them in SecureCRT and was able to login.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `Sftp()` (the `function(err)...`) is where you want to place your `conn.cd(...` code. It (said 2nd argument) is a function that gets called once the connection has been established. Make sure to check for `err` of course.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but the callback is not even invoked...leading me to believe that the connection itself is not established. I am not sure how i can debug as to why it is not able to connect.

Comment: Can you run tcpdump (or wireshark) on your end?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `exec()` method after commands.

```
conn
  .cd(".")
  .ls()
  .exec(
    function(err, res) { 
      console.log(res.data)
    }
  );
```